# Visual Studio - 'Browse UDDI Servers' -> 404?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-services, visual-studio-2005, uddi

I have a ASP.Net application which implements a web service. Within the ASP.Net application there's a test script which consumes the web service and it all works etc.

I have built a .NET console application and want to 'Add a Web Reference' so that the console app can consume the web service provided by the ASP.NET application. When I use the 'Browse UDDI Servers on the local network' to do that any plausible URL I use results in a 404.

I'm guessing I need to do something to my ASP.Net application so that it acts as an UDDI server ? Does anyone know what ?

**Update**

I just wanted to clarify something - I'm not desperate to use UDDI it just seems that's the only option in my circumstances which are :

- I'm actually doing this for another developer who is used to using Visual Studio to do this stuff
- The other developers system will need to run on another machine within the same network.

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm going to answer my own question here.

The key thing for me was that I didn't need an UDDI server in the first place - instead what I needed to do was to simply supply the 'Add Web Reference' dialog box with the URL for the .ASMX file within the ASP.NET application which defined the service I was after (and ignore the whole 'Browse UDDI Servers' thing). *(I've actually done this before but was having a bad-brain day today)*

More generally however if I did wish to use UDDI the answer I wanted appears to be here [MSDN Forum post dated July 2007 -](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/7b089b0a-d620-4b62-a8a8-559507c0dd0a)

```
> How do we add the UDDI server that we
> created to the local network?  ...
> Just found where to do that :
> 
> - Go to the UDDI Service Control MMC
> 
> - Right click on the server and go to properties
> 
> - Go to the "Active Directory" Tab
> 
> - Click "Publish"
```

Answer (score 0):

UDDI is a dedicated service on the network for registering Web Services and also for discovering/consuming web services.  Think of it as a directory of web services for a local intranet.

Windows Server 2003 includes UDDI Services.  You have to install it via Add/Remove -> Windows Components (similar to IIS, FrontPage Extensions, etc.).

If the problem is having a single repository of web services that can be discovered, then UDDI is a solution.

If the problem is using a single service on another machine, then just referencing an endpoint (asmx/svc) will suffice.  UDDI is overkill in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the OP did not actually want anything to do with UDDI. His assumption was false. UDDI is not actually used for anything.